# Getting error while running application on my physical device

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run my application on my physical device, but getting error says, duplicate class searched for the solution but didn't get.
below are the error codes that are been displayed while I try to run my application on my physical device.

it says that some file is duplicate but I am unable to understand the real deal with the code.

Help me so that I can launch my app.

```
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdi found in modules jetified-play-services-appinvite-16.0.4-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.4) and play-services-measurement-base-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdj found in modules jetified-play-services-appinvite-16.0.4-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.4) and play-services-measurement-base-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdk found in modules jetified-play-services-appinvite-16.0.4-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.4) and play-services-measurement-base-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.2.1)

  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzds found in modules jetified-play-services-appinvite-16.0.4-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.4) and play-services-measurement-base-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.2.1)

  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)

  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzas found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)

  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbo found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbp found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbq found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbr found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbs found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbt found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzc found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzco found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcp found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcq found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcr found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcs found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzct found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcv found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcw found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcx found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcy found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzcz found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzd found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzda found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdb found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdc found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdd found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzde found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdf found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdg found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdh found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdi found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdj found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdk found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdl found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdm found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdn found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdo found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdp found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdq found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdr found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzds found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdt found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdv found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdw found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdx found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdy found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdz found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zze found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzea found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeb found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzec found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzed found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzee found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzef found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeg found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeh found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzei found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzej found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzek found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeq found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzer found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzes found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzet found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzev found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzf found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfh found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfi found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfj found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfk found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfm found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzg found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzh found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-sdk-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:17.2.1)

  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzy found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

build.gradle(app)

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


  android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nanb.alpha"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

}
```

Comment: please add your Gradle file as well

Comment: Gradle file is added

Comment: make sure you are using all the latest dependencies.

Comment: may be this could help.. have a look https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases

Comment: I've checked the dependencies for you, and it looks like all libraries have been updated to the latest version, try to exclude **com.google.android.gms** `implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0') {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" 
}`